# Adding custom nodetypes to Apache Sling WebApp

Tags: java, apache, aem, jackrabbit, sling

I'm trying to figure out a way to add custom nodetypes **using a CND file** to my Sling WebApp. I downloaded the WAR file and got it running but since all the code is already compiled (as .class files), I can't add code to read the CND file and add the custom nodetypes.

On a separate note, I do have Jackrabbit running and with it, I can use the JackrabbitNodeTypeManager or other ways to code reading a CND file and adding nodetypes. This works on my local repository that is not running on a server.

I want to be able to add new nodetypes to the Sling Web Application in a similar way. So I'll boil my questions down to:

1. Is there a way to code the addition of new nodetypes in the Sling WebApp?
2. How can I connect my Jackrabbit repository (local) to the Sling Web Application (on server) so that I can possibly explore adding custom nodetypes this way (as I'm doing on my Jackrabbit repo locally at the moment)?

I understand that Sling is a framework that uses Jackrabbit as a repo and provides REST-like services to work with the repository, but I imagine there's a way to add these custom nodetypes just like Jackrabbit allows.

Thanks.

Comment: How do you currently connect to your Jackrabbit repository outside of Sling? It should be possible to do so with Sling as well.

Comment: The Sling WebApp comes with the Jackrabbit repository layered underneath out-of-box. As for my separate Jackrabbit project that's simply placed locally, something simple like: `Repository repository = new TransientRepository(); Session session = repository.login(new SimpleCredentials("username", "password".toCharArray()));`. I've been following the Jackrabbit First Hops tutorial for the latter.

Comment: I see. The simplest way to connect to the JCR repository is to deploy a bundle doing all the work to Sling.

Comment: I didn't know it was possible to connect to the repository by deploying an OSGi bundle. I'll investigate this a little more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to code the addition of new nodetypes in the Sling WebApp?

This is documented at [Declared Node Type Registration](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/content-loading-jcr-contentloader.html#declared-node-type-registration). What you need to do is

- write the node type definition in CND format
- place it in a bundle
- reference the file in the manifest using the `Sling-Nodetypes` header
- deploy the bundle to your Sling app